# When the sort field is not the part of shard key, will mongos sort the data returned by all mongod?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

When the sort field is not part of the shard key, mongos will send the query to all mongod instances. After all mongod instances return data, mongos will merge them.

Does this merge operation include a sort?

We know the sort field is not part of the shard key, so the returned data should be unordered, mongos must do sort. If so, when the returned data is very large, mongos will take up a lot of memory.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 4):

It's not the sort field that needs to be in the shard key, but rather the criteria you are using to select the data.  That is, if the mongos cannot determine from the fields you are using as part of your query where the data lives specifically then it will send to all shards.  This is the same as any other non-sort query.  Sorting on a non-shardkey field does not affect the ability of the mongos to route the queries appropriately.

This is mentioned in the docs here:

https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#how-mongos-handles-query-modifiers

The shards will receive the queries from mongos, they will sort their subset of results, and send them back to the mongos.  The mongos then has to do a merge sort on the returned results before presenting them back.  This is not as intensive as the full sort would be, since the results are ordered initially by the shards, but will still require resources.  The amount of memory consumed will be related to the size of the result sets returned by the various shards.

**Edit (May 2016):** the above was true when originally answered in 2012, but (as pointed out in the comments below) the behavior changed with version 2.6 in 2014.  The [results are now sent](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#how-mongos-handles-query-modifiers) to the primary shard for the sharded database to be merge sorted before being returned to the mongos (and then to the user).  This makes a lot of sense since `mongos` instances are far less likely to have the resources to perform a large sort, but it does mean that you should pay close attention to where any databases which will be sorted frequently have their primary as it will see higher load as a result.

Comment: Thanks！ Adam， you are always actively answer my question.

Comment: @Adam Comeford Acording to https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#how-mongos-handles-query-modifiers a merg sort is performed by the "primary" shard, not mongos!

Comment: Looks like that changed in 2.6 (which was released almost 2 years after I wrote this answer) - if you look at the docs for 2.4 here: https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#how-mongos-handles-query-modifiers then you'll see the mongos incremental merge sort referenced.  Perfect example of why you should always check the date of an answer on SO :) That being said, I will update the answer to reflect the new behavior to avoid confusion for others - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In 3.2 version, if primary shard is not used in fetch (in other words, the primary shard does NOT contain any of the documents in the find command), then a secondary shard may be used instead.